# How to append an ID value of a list element to a link with .json?

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatting, sharepoint-2019

I need your help with something and Id be very grateful.

Lets say I'm having a SharePoint list with different list elements. Every list element has a specific ID.

What I am trying to do is for example I'm having a column formatted as a text field. I'm trying to write a .json code that appends the value of the ID of the list element to a link

I did try it with the following code

```
{ "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json", "debugMode": true, "elmType": "div", "children": [ { "elmType": "a", "attributes": { "target": "_blank", "href": { "operator": "+", "operands": [ "http://anywebsite?ID='", "[$ID]" ] } }, "txtContent": "Some text" } ] }
```

But when I click ok then in the SharePoint column it gives me an error:

```
Failure: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of null
```

Now what can I do to append the ID to a Link in a different column ?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: yeah excuse me Im a beginner in .json

Answer (score 0):

I test Hyperlink filed, there is one ' which doesn't need in your json.

```
{ "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json", "debugMode": true, "elmType": "div", "children": [ { "elmType": "a", "attributes": { "target": "_blank", "href": { "operator": "+", "operands": [ "http://anywebsite?ID=", "[$ID]" ] } }, "txtContent": "Some text" } ] }
```

[image]